# Why wont my labels change onClick

Tags: android

I have gone into my AndroidManifest.xml and changed the labels to my string resources, however when i launch the application on my phone, it only dislays the "numbers" label. I did have success changing it from Miwac to The numbers label, but now the numbers label is displayed for every activity.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
 Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.miwok">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_numbers"
           />

        <activity android:name=".Colors"
        android:label="@string/category_colors"    />

        <activity android:name=".Phrases"
        android:label="@string/category_phrases"    />

        <activity android:name=".FamilyMembers"
            android:label="@string/category_family"
            >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my mainActivity.java

---

```
 package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.android.miwok.R.id.phrases;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Find the View that shows the numbers category
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);

// Set a click listener on that View
        numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(numbersIntent);
            }
        });
        TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);

// Set a click listener on that View
        family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(familyIntent);
            }
        });TextView colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);

// Set a click listener on that View
        colors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent colorsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(colorsIntent);
            }
        });TextView phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);

// Set a click listener on that View
        phrases.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent phrasesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(phrasesIntent);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every new intent you are launching same "NumbersActivity".. Replace them with other activities

```
 Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
 startActivity(numbersIntent);

 Intent colorsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Colors.class);
 startActivity(colorsIntent);

 Intent phrasesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Phrases.class);
 startActivity(phrasesIntent);
```